# Why are these sets closed?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, limits

Consider the sets in $\mathbb R^2$ defined by

$$A=\left\{(x,\frac1x)|x>0\right\}\\ B=\left\{\left(x,−\frac1x\right)|x<0\right\}$$

Lets assume $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $A$ but not in $A$. Then it has to be in $B$, right? Then $x$ has to be negative. Is that a contradiction to $(x, y)$ is a limit point of $A$? Why or why not?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: "*Then it has to be in B, right?*" What makes you think so ?

Comment: Note that $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint closed sets.

Comment: They are closed because they are graph of continuous functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=|x|y-1$.

Then $f$ is continuous and so its zero set $Z$ is closed.

Now, $A= Z \cap Q_1$ and $B=Z \cap Q_2$, where $Q_i$ is the closed $i$-th quadrant.

Therefore, both $A$ and $B$ are closed, being the intersection of two closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets assume $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $A$ but not in $A$. Then it has to be in $B$, right?

$A$ is a closed set, so there is no point $(x,y)$ which is a limit point of $A$ but is not in $A$.

---

**Technically**, of course, that means that the statement

"If $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $A$, but not in $A$, then $(x,y)$ is in $B$"

is a true statement, but it also means that the statement

"If $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $A$, but not in $A$, then $(x,y)$ is not $B$"

Along with that, other true statements include

"If $(x,y)$ is a limit point of $A$, but not in $A$, then $1+1=3$"

Comment: A closed set you mean?

Comment: @Markus Yes. Typo.

Comment: I still don't really get why A is closed. It's obvious but i am looking for a proof and somehow cant find any

Comment: @Markus That's a totally different question than the one you posted here.

Comment: I am looking for a proof / explanation why a limit point of A has to be in A and a limit point of B has to be in B.

Comment: @Markus Then you are looking for an explanation why $A$ is closed, and I don't know why you didn't just ask *that*. I answered the question you **asked**, not the one you **wanted** to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Hint if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =a ~~~and ~~~\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{x_n} =b$$ both exist then $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0.$ and $a=\frac{1}{b}$